# Problems with installation of VS 2012 (.Net is missing)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation

I'm having trouble installing Visual Studio 2012. When I run the installer I get the message:

> Microsoft .NET Framework required for Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 setup

The first time I got this message, I clicked to install. It loaded some stuff but it didn't look like it installed anything. I ran the installer for VS 2012 again and I get the same message but now without any buttons to click on. Is there any solution to this?

---

**What happened before**

I had VS 2012 already up and working. I left it alone for quite a while until I decided I wanted to do some programming again. Starting the application resulted suddenly in an error:

> Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.

After searching for a couple of hours I couldn't resolve the problem so I did as it asked and reinstalled VS, but I got the same error again. Then I tried to remove every single application VS installs as indicated by [this list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2744926) and any program that had a similar name. I also removed all .NET versions and C++ redistributables. Now I can't install VS anymore and some games and gadgets are now broken.

And I always, always, always forget the existence of system restore. I doubt my oldest system restore is old enough. This is going to be my last resort.

**What I tried**

- Search for a .NET installation in the control panel, it's not present after clicking the install button on the prompt of the VS 2012 installer.
- Reinstall .NET 4.5 using [this installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653). It installs correctly, but the problem persists.
- Turning .NET 3.5.1 off from windows features and install it manually. This fails for an unknown reason (error code -2145124329, which seems undefined). Just turning it off doesn't work either.